# Close a spring reactive WebClient call inside a request handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am attempting to proxy a streaming HTTP call
by placing a Flux emitting client in a streaming controller method as follows:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/api/v1/data/flux", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> streamDataFlux() {

        WebClient cl = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com")
                .build();

        return cl.post().uri("/api/events")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "keep-alive")
                .bodyValue("")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class);
}
```

**How do I ensure the client is cancelled if and when the calling response handler is cancelled?**

I.e. If I `cURL` my URL, (/api/v1/data/flux) then CTRL-C that request ... the WebClient remains connected seemingly permanently...

Thx

Comment: Why do you think "WebClient remains connected seemingly permanently"? as soon as you stop `cURL` streamDataFlux should receive `cancel` signal that will be propagated to the `WebClient` and request will be canceled as well. You could add `.log()` at the end of your flow to observe this behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Well the decoder still prints line codec output and `netstat` still shows the java process having a TCP connection to the endpoint.  When I ctrl-C spring-boot it prints details about the open conneciton as it closes. (Incidentally As you mention `log` - I haven't managed to get the data re-codec-ed to the output. Not sure why but a few more things to try before I raise another SO ;) )